# React Native Maps Google Directions Toolbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using React native maps (Google Maps) when I tap on marker directions toolbar show in Android but this toolbar not showing in the iOS.

Is there any way to show this in iOS too.

```
<MapView 
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: lon,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                    }}
                    minZoomLevel={16}
                    provider='google'
                >
                    <MapView.Marker 
                        coordinate={{
                            latitude: lat,
                            longitude: lon
                        }}
                        title={address}
                    >
                        <Image resizeMode={'contain'} source={{ uri: markerIconUrl }} size={'xs'} alt={address} />
                    </MapView.Marker>
                </MapView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it's not available on iOS according the documentation:

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

"Android only If false will hide 'Navigate' and 'Open in Maps' buttons on marker press"

But I'm interested to find solution also.

**UPD:**
There is the solution.

I created custom direction button for iOS and used deeplink to call the specify feature of google map. This is my method:

```
onDirectionButton() {
    const lat = this.state.directionLat;
    const lng = this.state.directionLng;
    const scheme = Platform.select({ios: 'maps:0,0?q=', android: 'geo:0,0?q='});
    const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
    const label = 'Custom Label';
    const url = Platform.select({
        ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
        android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
    });

    Linking.openURL(url)
}
```